# Spring REST - pass PDF through a request

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, pdf, document

I have got 2 Spring Boot Applications...
First application should generate a PDF and return it... Second Application is calling first application to get the pdf and return it to user...

Here i am generating a pdf.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/html2pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> report(@RequestParam() String htmlContent) {

        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream pdfDocument = pdfGenerator.generatePDF(htmlContent);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
            headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=generated.pdf");

            return ResponseEntity
                    .ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfDocument));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
    }
```

Here i am trying to make a call against first application and return the pdf...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pdfreport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> report() {

        ResourceHttpMessageConverter resourceHttpMessageConverter = new ResourceHttpMessageConverter();

        List<MediaType> supportedApplicationTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        MediaType pdfApplication = new MediaType("application", "pdf");
        supportedApplicationTypes.add(pdfApplication);

        resourceHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedApplicationTypes);
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(resourceHttpMessageConverter);

        RestTemplate pdfGenerator = new RestTemplate();
        pdfGenerator.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response = pdfGenerator.getForEntity("http://localhost:1080/pdf-generator/html2pdf?htmlContent=<h2>HUHU</h2>", InputStreamResource.class);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=generated.pdf");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(response.getBody());
    }
```

in this constellation i get following error:

```
java.io.IOException: stream is closed
```

I have already tried it with ResponseExtractor...

What is the problem here? How can i solve it more easy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InputStreamResource Should only be used if no other specific Resource implementation is applicable. In particular, prefer ByteArrayResource or any of the file-based Resource implementations where possible.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html